# Calcular diferença entre datas com fuso horario

Tags: php, datetime

Preciso calcular a diferença entre 2 datas com fuso horario diferente:
O calculo é entre a data de postagem e a data corrente.

> Supondo que uma postagem seja de `America/Sao_Paulo` e outra de `Europe/Amsterdam`.
>   Para cada entrada de registro eu devo manter o timezone do usuario ou o do servidor?

Como devo fazer para computar a diferença quando um usuario for ler a postagem do outro?
Caso o usuario de São Paulo acesse o post de Amsterdam, como mostar que foi a X minutos?

Não sei a melhor forma de gravar o momento de entrada dos posts...

Comment: Você poderia ter uma tabela no banco que guardasse as transações, guardar o horário da postagem e o horário da recepção do produto e após isso calcular (já que você já tem os dois horários salvos em banco).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sugiro que faça a conversão para uma timezone comum ao armazenar a data da postagem (timezone do servidor por exemplo).

Ao exibir a data para o usuário, converta a data armazenada no servidor usando `DateTime`

```
<?php

// String timezone - America/Sao_Paulo exemplo
$timezoneServer = $config['timezoneDefault'];

$date = new DateTime('2014-07-25', new DateTimeZone($timezoneServer));
// Pode-se omitir o segundo parametro para usar o padrão do servidor
// $date = new DateTime('2014-07-25);

// Rotina para recuperar o Timezone do usuário
$userTimezone = $userModel->getUserTimeZone();

// Recupera a data do post e converte para a Timezone do usuário
$postDate = new DateTime($post->date, new DateTimeZone($userTimezone));

// "P" exibe a representação em relação a GMT (-03:00, -02:30)
echo $postDate->format('Y-m-d  H:i:sP');
```

Comment: deu erro em `toFormat`, troquei por `format` e funcionou, obrigado

Comment: Escrevi o codigo direto do site. Editado

Answer (score 1):

Sugiro que salve os registros com a timezone do servidor e calcule a diferença no momento de exibir (contando que você tenha salvo a timezone de cada usuário).

- Quando for exibir que a postagem foi a X minutos, apenas calcule a diferença entre agora e o momento da postagem.
- Quando for exibir a data e hora da postagem, calcule a diferença entre a timezone do servidor e do usuário.

Para isso, utilize a classe DateTime do PHP (PHP >= 5.2).
Docs.: http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Exemplo:

```
// cria obj com a tz do servidor
$datetime = new DateTime($post->datetime);
// seta a tz do obj com a tz do usuário (isso já converte a datetime do post)
$datetime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($user->timezone));
// imprime
echo $datetime->format('d/m/Y H:i');
```

Comment: as 2 respostas são praticamente idênticas. obrigado Lucas