# Como comparar intervalo de tempo do post desde que foi publicado ?

Tags: php, mysql

Boas pessoal,

Tenho uma tabela onde crio os posts em que cada um e adicionado a data em que foi publicado,
agora preciso de criar um sistema para no post aparecer a quanto tempo foi publicado tipo o facebook gostava da vossa ajuda para saber qual a melhor forma de fazer isso e como o poderei fazer ?

Comment: Veja se essa [*questão*](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/26383/13412) ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Você tem que trabalhar com timestamp.

Eu salvo as datas no banco usando:

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

Que é o padrão para timestamp/datatime do mysql.

Agora que você tem um padrão salvo, ao ler isso você converter a data (que vem como string) para o formato de data com

```
strtotime
```

ficando:

```
strtotime($suadatadobanco);
```

Então você vai usar novamente da função data() para pegar os campos da data que você quer, se quer apenas o dia use 'd', exemplo:

```
date('d', strtotime($suadatadobanco))
```

O retorno será o dia do mês daquela data.

Para mais informações sobre a função date acesse:  http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php

Agora você sabe pegar as datas e seus elementos, agora falta calcular a diferença de data.

Para fazer isso você transforma as datas em timestamp e então faz as operações, lembrando que o timestamp converte a data completa em segundos, ou seja, você soma, subtrai, divide e multiplica as datas usando segundos, depois  de fazer isso então você pega o resultado e converte de volta para data.

Exemplo:

Você quer caber a diferença da data_1 em relação a data_2, então você vai fazer assim:

```
$diferenca_em_timestamp = strtotime($suadatadobanco_data_1) - strtotime($suadatadobanco_data_2);

$difenca_em_dia = date('d', strtotime($diferenca_em_timestamp));
```

Você pode criar um script do tipo "se a data for acima de 7 dias, exiba 'mais de uma semana'" ou "se for menos de 60min exiba 'há poucos minutos'"... isso vai da sua lógia e do que precisa...

Mas existem plugins de javascript que pegam a data que você dá e faz essa "conversão" para dias/min/meses...

Veja o plugin:

https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat

Comment: Obrigado pela sua sugestão mas eu já tinha resolvido praticamente dessa forma acabei por converter em strtotime e fazer as verificações através de switch mas obrigado pela sua resposta assim que me for possível vou colocar o código como resposta para o caso de outra pessoa precisar